# How do I make fancybox href dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have the following fancybox code:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
             'autoScale' : false,
             'href' : $('.fancybox').attr('id'),
             'type':'iframe',
             'padding' : 0,
             'closeClick'  : false,

//some other callbacks etc
```

the problem is I have twenty different A tag id's on the page and I want the fancybox href attribute to take the id of the clicked element, ie the one that triggered the event.

I have tried several things, none of them have worked!

```
'href' : $(this).attr('id'),
'href' : $(this.element).attr('id'),
```

This seems so simple but anytime I plug in 'this' or similar nothing works.

Comment: what is the difference between using the `id` attribute and the `href` attribute? ... let html do what it does better (without overusing jQuery) you can have 20 different IDs in your `<a>` tags but all of them can share the same `class="fancybox"` so your script above will work seamlessly and without over complicating things.

Comment: following up my previous comment, you just remove the `href` API option and fancybox will take it from the `href` attribute in the `<a>` tag.

Comment: my href's though are non standard, client doesn't want twenty different links on page so I am using href's with "#" in them and at some point in the code I need the JS to send it to the real href which I was storing in id. Open to suggestions!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Without `each()` or `click()` simply add the `beforeLoad` callback to your script like this

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    autoScale: false,
    // href : $('.fancybox').attr('id'), // don't need this
    type: 'iframe',
    padding: 0,
    closeClick: false,
    // other options
    beforeLoad: function () {
        var url = $(this.element).attr("id");
        this.href = url
    }
}); // fancybox
```

**NOTE**: this is for fancybox v2.0.6+

On the other hand, a more **elegant** solution is to use (HTML5) `data-*` attribute to set the `href` (it would look weird to set `id="images/01.jpg"` otherwise) so you could do :

```
<a href="#" id="id01" data-href="images/01.jpg" ...
```

and your callback

```
beforeLoad: function(){
 var url= $(this.element).data("href");
 this.href = url
}
```

and use the `id` attribute for what is meant for.

---

**EDIT** : The best is to use the special `data-fancybox-href` attribute in your anchor like :

```
<a id="item01" data-fancybox-href="http://jsfiddle.net" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"  href="javascript:;">jsfiddle</a>
```

and use a simple script without callback like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // API options 
    autoScale: false,
    type: 'iframe',
    padding: 0,
    closeClick: false
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SH6m9/)</kbd>

Comment: ahh perfect...I had tried a few things in the beforeload callback but I must have just been a bit off. Thanks again this worked perfect, you've helped me get through a lot of this fancybox stuff!

Comment: Thanks for this. I needed to append an ajax flag to my url so I could serve up a chromeless modal template, while keeping the url in tact for crawlers, screen readers and _open in new window_ clicks.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over your collection of `.fancybox` items and grab the id.

```
$('.fancybox').each(function(){
    $(this).fancybox({
             'autoScale' : false,
             'href' : $(this).attr('id'),
             'type':'iframe',
             'padding' : 0,
             'closeClick'  : false,
             //some other callbacks etc
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(".fancybox").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('id');
    $.fancybox({
         'autoScale' : false,
         'href' : url ,
         'type':'iframe',
         'padding' : 0,
         'closeClick'  : false,
         //some other callbacks etc
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.fancybox').each( function() {
    var elem = jQuery(this);
    elem.fancybox({
             'autoScale' : false,
             'href' : elem.attr('id'),
             'type':'iframe',
             'padding' : 0,
             'closeClick'  : false,
          });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$('.fancybox').each(function(){
    $(this).fancybox({
         'autoScale' : false,
         'href' : this.id,
         'type':'iframe',
         'padding' : 0,
         'closeClick'  : false,
          //some other callbacks etc
    });
});
```