# Basic Fancybox code have no effects

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I don't understand why this simple code is not running.

I've miss something but i don't see what :

Html :

```
<span class="test" url="mapage.php">It's a test</span>
```

Javascript :

```
 jQuery(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.test').on('click', function () {
            //alert($(this).attr('url'));
            $.fancybox({ 'href': $(this).attr('url') });
        });
    });

});
```

I don't have any error in firebug.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6ZZJH/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues :
First: you should write your code like that :

```
$(function () {
 //your code here
});
```

It will fire your code only when jQuery is ready.

Secondly, in your case inside your jsfiddle, fancybox lib isn't loaded.

you should add that:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

Then finally, your url must be a picture:

Like that:

```
<span class="test" url="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2647/3867677191_04d8d52b1a.jpg">It's a test</span>
```

Here the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5QYGe/1/

Comment: I have change the link of jsfiddle, it was yours... sorry for that.

Comment: No problem but why it must be an image? If i want to load my page for example, i can't? Thanks for your help

Comment: I find my reply : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618221/how-do-i-make-fancybox-href-dynamic Thanks !

Comment: fancy box does not have to be loaded in jsfiddle... it should in your own html. Your url doesn't have to be a picture... it can be a normal html page to... in that case you need to specify the type to iframe. see my answer.

Comment: You are right, but as I wasn't sure of that; I take that direction ;)

Answer (score 2):

first you have nested document ready functions...

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.test').on('click', function () {
        //alert($(this).attr('url'));
        $.fancybox({ 'href': $(this).attr('url') });
    });
});
```

or which is shorthand for above.

```
 $(function () {

        $('.test').on('click', function () {
            //alert($(this).attr('url'));
            $.fancybox({ 'href': $(this).attr('url') });
        });
});
```

> **UPDATE** 
>   Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/6ZZJH/9/
>   if you want to open a url you'll need to specify fancybox type to
>   iframe...

```
            $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.test').click(function () {

                btn=$(this);

                btn.fancybox({
                    "type": 'iframe',
                    "href": btn.attr('url')
                });


            });
        });
```

Comment: that is because, fancybox is not included in jquery. You have to include it to your html as a script tag. If not it doesn't get loaded. Have a look at the documentation of fancybox

Answer (score 0):

```
  jQuery(function () {
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.test').on('click', function () {
        //alert($(this).attr('url'));
        $.fancybox({ 'href': $(this).attr('url') });
    });
 });

});
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').on('click', function () {
        //alert($(this).attr('url'));
        $.fancybox({ 'href': $(this).attr('url') });
    });
 });
```

And make sure you have included **jquery.fancybox.version.js** and **jquery.fancybox.version.css** inside the html.