# Fancybox for image library; if href empty or # then take image SRC as source

Tags: jquery, fancybox

we have an image library and I am trying to achieve the following

We use fancybox
and images are placed with `<a>` wrapped around it and `href=#`
what I would like is, that: `if href empty or #` 
and only when `img` tag (only if image)
then take image `SRC` as the fancybox link source

**Question:** Can this be done like the method? Or is there a default setting to trigger this behavior?

Link to supporting question: [How do I make fancybox href dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618221/how-do-i-make-fancybox-href-dynamic)

Comment: When you have `<img src="{image.jpg}" />` it's normally used to show thumbnails that point to a larger version of the same image within the `href` of the `<a>` tag so saving bandwidth and speeding up the page load. But if you are already showing the big image within the `src` attribute, what's the point to show the same image in fancybox? unless you are down-scaling the image (in `img`) via css, which wouldn't be recommended.

Comment: then it would be useful if you post a sample of the html code where this condition should apply.