# Script shop Ajax response in fancybox

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

i try open with fancy box iframe with content of product page without header, sidebar and other.

There is my link

```
<a rel="example_group" class="fancy_view" data-id="{$product_info[11]}" data-href="{$product_info[13]}" href="#fancy_popup">Увеличить</span></a>
```

and this is jquery

```
$( ".fancy_view" ).click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var link = $(this).data('href');
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: link,
            data: "id=" + id + "&ajax=1",
            success: function(result){
                $.fancybox(result, {
                    'type'  : 'iframe',
                    'width' : 600,
                    'height': 500
                });

            },
        });
    return false;
});
```

in console i see response with content, but in iframe - 404 error. 
where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/v7nbLuzr/

```
$.fancybox({
  'content'  : result,
  'width' : 600,
  'height': 500
});
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

Add beforeLoad with your `link` variable like following

```
        success: function(result){
            $.fancybox(result, {
                'type'  : 'iframe',
                'width' : 600,
                'height': 500,
                beforeLoad : function(){
                this.href = link
               }
            });
          }
```

**[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618221/how-do-i-make-fancybox-href-dynamic)**

Comment: what you get in `result`?

Comment: <div class="item">
        <div class="img"><a href="./Композиция состоит из 3 разноцветных шариков, размером 30 см, расположенных на единой ленте, декорированной маленькими шариками.<br />
"><img id="dp894" src="./products_pictures/kompozitsiya-trio-894-S.jpg" alt="Композиция ..... and lot of HTML

Comment: maybe i don`t need iframe? maybe i need inline?