# How to open gallery using jQuery or Javascript if image located in table gets clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gallery, image-gallery

I have a bootstrap table which contains information about real estates:[image]

Each real estate has **many** images. I just show one of them in bootstrap table. What I want is when user clicks on the existing image I want to show other related ones as gallery using jQuery or Javascript. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: You can use a plugin such as http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: I'll check it. Thanx

Comment: Fancybox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618221/how-do-i-make-fancybox-href-dynamic